# WordPress site layout broken in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am having an IE8 css problem on a WordPress site.  The layout keeps breaking and everything shifts to the left on the home page.  Of course it is driving the client crazy and I need a fix this morning. Any IE8 gurus out there that can help?  http://stat-management.net

Comment: The site is offline and you have to be more specific about your problem.

Comment: oh shoot it is http://stat-management.net ...sorry

Comment: I have the proper size header image from the client and will be changing it out as soon as I fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

IE should have been taken out back and shot. Try adding:

```
body {
   text-align: center;
}
#page {
   text-align: left;
}
```

And this will fix the (quirks mode) problem.